# swift 3 como abrir um popover de forma que não cubra toda viewcontroller que a chamou?

Tags: ios, swift, popover

Eu já utilizo o popover que é aberto através de uma "segue" e gostaria que pudesse definir as dimensões (altura e largura) deste popover para que não cobrisse completamente a viewcontroller que a abriu.
Utilizo as seguintes instruções na viewcontroller:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "callDriverPopupSegue", sender: self)


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "callDriverPopSegue" {
        let popOver = segue.destination as! CallDriverPopup
        popOver.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popOver.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
    }
}
```

E no popover incluí o UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate:

```
class CallDriverPopup: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja [aqui](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/preferredContentSize) uma explicação da Apple, em inglês porém ótima

Segue também um exemplo de como setar tamanho.

```
> let height = yourDataArray.count *
> Int(popOverViewController.tableView.rowHeight)
> popOverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300,
> height: height)
```